# Can I work out my question to reopen it?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions

The close reason given to my [just closed question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/169739/21486) is... let's say not quite entirely correct.

Wikipedia mobile app is an open source. Someone with enough knowledge (I don't have it!) could theoretically access the source code of the functionality in question and answer me, why it is now working like it is working (the key reason of my question).

Does this still make my question off-topic? Or can I salvage it somehow (going the above way)?

Answer (score -1):

Questions about mobile apps are off-topic here.
Questions about open-source code are off-topic here too.

Mentioning mobile apps and open-source without clearly stating how that is relavent to using a the respective webapp doesn't help to make your question to be a good fit for this site. What could help is:

1. Remove the "noise" / chitchat. Ref [Expected Behavior](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).
2. Focus on the description of what you are trying to do and the expected result.
3. Share what you have tried to fix the problem by your self.
   Usually using a web browser in private navigation / incognito mode and using a different computer might, among other troubleshooting steps are helpful details. All users should have tried something.
   If you know about the HTML, CSS, JavaScript and the web broswer developer tools you might have a wide range of options to try. It might also helpful that you share if you tried something, but this is optional
4. Share what you found from this site and from, in this case Wikipedia official resources for end-users and why the didn't meet your needs. In the worst case, show what you tried to find those resources, be specific. Saying things like "I googled but found nothing" doesn't help anyone".

Points 2 to 4 are my interpretation of [How do I ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). If you find that this does not go with you, follow the guidance direcltly from that articly. You also might find helpful [Why do I see a message that my question does not meet quality standards?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. This question **is not** about mobile application. It is about _Wikipedia website / webservice_. I only mentioned mobile Wikipedia app as an example. This question **is not** about open source. I only mentioned that looking into it could be a source for answer. It is about a behaviour that I've found puzzling in one of the websites and I am asking others if are experiencing these same problem and know the solution. I will try to fix the question, taking your advices. I already know the answer to this question, but can post it until close is retracted.